# How do you debug functions from includes in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, debugging, include

The implementation of [ScrumJet on GitHub](http://github.com/AlainODea/scrumjet) (as of this writing) shares essentially identical functions between the storage modules for tasks, categories and boards.  This was achieved by moving the identical code which makes heavy use of the `?MODULE` macro into `scrumjet_datastore.hrl`.  Each of `scrumjet_task.erl`, `scrumjet_category.erl` and `scrumjet_board.erl` include `scrumjet_datastore.hrl` and have no functions defined locally.

This works very well when there is nothing wrong.  However, if I need to debug, then the debugger brings up the empty module instead of the header file where the functions are defined.

Does anyone know how to make the Erlang debugger work for functions in includes?

Comment: The easiest would be that you simply copy-paste the code from the header file to the module sources and recompile.

Comment: In my opinion scrumjet_datastore should be an erlang module, every function taking the table name as an additional argument. Instead of calling into those "empty" modules, calls could be made to scrumjet_datastore with the table name passed as well...

Comment: I agree with Zed, unless you know a specific reason for needing and .hrl-file and macros, go with normal modules and parameters as much as you can. This simplifies a lot. Don't worry about performance or inlining just yet.

Comment: Thank you Zed and Adam.  You guys are right.

Records complicate parameterization because they cannot be variables at runtime when used in pattern matching or calls to `record_info/2`.

However, the `scrumjet_datastore` module can be parameterized with a helper function for getting the record_info(fields, ...) of a record at runtime:
<pre>
fields(scrumjet_task) -> record_info(fields, scrumjet_task);
fields(scrumjet_category) -> record_info(fields, scrumjet_category);
fields(scrumjet_board) -> record_info(fields, scrumjet_board).
</pre>

Helper functions would also be needed for the queries.

Comment: Thank you Zed :)

Thank you Adam Lindberg :)

I have [refactored ScrumJet to use a single datastore module with parameterized functions (Commit beb68b66)][http://github.com/AlainODea/scrumjet/commit/beb68b667a60b41700ec1886d393a8327a075064].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using includes in Erlang to share implementations of functions is not generally a good idea.  It has some uses, but it should be avoided in regular application code.

As I mentioned back in 2009 I followed Zed and Adam Lindberg's advice and used a datastore module with parameterized methods instead.